# How do I move eyes with a body?

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging, armature

I have a spider and I animated it, the issue, when it moves, the eyes don't really follow and just move around which gives a stupid look to the spider.

Is there an easy fix for that? The eyes and the body are joined

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file so that we understand what's wrong?

Comment: Not enough details! You say that the eyes are joined to the body. Are they now part of the same mesh and did you join them before you started animating? If you joined them after you parented the armature you may need to weight paint them to follow the rest of the rig. As @moonboots says we'll need to see your Blend file. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Hello, I published an updated version, can you check it out and tell me if you understand? Thank you very much